# getting different output from different compilers

Tags: c, string

The question was:
Define a function getint(), which would receive a numeric string from keyboard, convert it to an integer number and return the integer to the calling function.

My code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

int getint();

int main()
{
    int a;
    a = getint();
    printf("you entered %d",a);
    return 0;
}

int getint()
{
    char str[10];

    printf("Enter number: ");
    gets(str);


    int d=0,len = strlen(str),r = len-1;

    for(int i=0;str[i] != '\0';i++,r--)
        d += (str[i]-48)*pow(10,r);

    return d;
}
```

while I run this program from sublime text or code block the output was coming wrong

output(from sublime and codeblocks):

> ```
> Enter number: 123
> you entered 122
> ```

But when I used onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler the output was coming correct

So how can output differ from compiler to compiler for the same program

Comment: Considering that a 32-bit `int` can hold a 10-digit decimal number, your string is not long enough. There is a good reason for [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) There is no need to use `pow`, it won't be accurate. To build a value, you simply multiply the current value by `10` and add the next digit. So `d = d * 10 + (str[i] -'0');`

Comment: maybe `pow(10, 2)` returns 99.99999996535764

Comment: the result depends on the compiler of the IDE ?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pow` function works with floating point numbers.  As such, the result may not be exactly equal to what you expect the numerical result to be.  For example, `pow(10,2)` could output a number slightly larger or slightly smaller than 100.  If the result is just below 100, the fractional part gets truncated and you're left with 99.

Rather than using `pow` for an integer power, just multiply the current value of `d` by 10 before adding the value for the next digit.

```
d = 10 * d + (str[i]-'0')
```

Comment: whoa.. it worked. But how come on online compiler results were coming correct before correcting code?

Comment: @UTPAL Different implementations have their own version of `pow`, each of which handles rounding slightly differently